# Can I use flex to put dividers on multiple rows?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to display multiple checkboxes on the screen. But I want the checkboxes to all line up vertically and horizontal to look like a grid.

The first thing that came to my mind is to use `flex` to do it. But I'm not sure how to use flex to auto wrap every 4 dividers.

Here is what I have done:

```css
.card
{
  flex : 1;
}

.flex-wrapper
{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrapper">

  <div class="card">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value=""> name 1
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value=""> name 2
    </label>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="card">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value=""> name 3
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value=""> name 4
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value=""> name 5
    </label>
  </div>

</div>
```

You can also use this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/he5qju8n/) to tinker with the code.

From this code I want to tell flex to start a new line after the 4th divider inside the flex-wrapper divider.

Is this something that can be done using flex or do I need to use css bootstrap grid system?

Comment: Try `flex: 0 0 25%`: https://jsfiddle.net/he5qju8n/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the checkboxes break to multiple rows on the 4th element, you can give your `.card` div's a `width: 25%;` (instead of `flex: 1;`), and give your `.flex-wrapper` a `flex-wrap: wrap;`

```css
.card
{
  width: 25%;
}

.flex-wrapper
{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrapper">

  <div class="card">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value=""> name 1
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value=""> name 2
    </label>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="card">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value=""> name 3
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value=""> name 4
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value=""> name 5
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value=""> name 6
    </label>
  </div>

</div>
```